# Adding ImageView on top of GLSurfaceView cause black screen on start

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588093/button-and-glsurfaceview#new-answer?newreg=644f206e72b4480c92e2a23e6a9b3436) to draw a button on top of GLSurfaceView very useful, but every time just after starting my app I got black-screen for some 500-1000 ms. After that evrything is drawn correctly.

Someone suggested to try this:

```
layout.requestTransparentRegion(button)
```

but this does not solve my problem. Still black screen on every start :(

Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find [How to avoid Black Screen on starting an application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585260/how-to-avoid-black-screen-on-starting-an-application) helpful.  You're probably just doing something in `onCreate` that takes enough time to cause the blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for reply but sry that link is not helpful for me. I am not doing any time/ressource consuming actions in 'onCreate' so that blank screen could be created because of that.

Comment: What are you doing in `onCreate`?  Have you tried commenting lines out to see if the app starts faster?

Comment: Without button code after 'setContentView' app starts allways immediately. Just tested it by commenting out evrything that could consume time...and there is no difference...black screen stays same amount of time there irrespective of how much is commented out...dont think this is my problem.

Comment: FWIW, the question linked asked specifically how to do it without involving the XML layout.  You can just let the view system manage it.  See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for a few examples.  I don't know what's causing your blank pause, so I don't know if it'll change things, but it's something to experiment with.